# threading.Timer alternative for coroutines

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, coroutine

Im creating a discord bot and I wanted to know if there is any third party libraries that do the same thing as threading.Timer but with coroutine support for Discord.client.send.

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['Timer'])
async def timer(ctx, secs, *message):
    await ctx.send(f"Your timer {message} started, and it is gonna take {secs}secs to stop.")

    async def stop_timer():
        await ctx.send(f'Your timer: {message} is over, it took {secs} secs.')

    def timer_over():
        asyncio.run(stop_timer())
        
    simpleTimer = threading.Timer(int(secs), timer_over)
    simpleTimer.start()
```

My code up there, im looking for a function that takes some seconds and after those seconds the function returns a coroutine. Kinda like an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `tasks` from `discord.ext`:

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def my_loop(messageable):
    await messageable.send("Here's some message!")

@bot.command()
async def startloop(ctx):
    my_loop.start(messageable=ctx)
```

This will send `Here's some message!` to whatever messageable object you give it every 30 seconds.

---

### References:

- [`ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)
- [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) - This is stuff like text channels, users, etc. You can see what inherits from it in the docs.
- [`Loop.stop()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.stop) - Stopping loops
- [`Loop.start()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.start) - Starting loops

Comment: tasks repeats the message every n seconds, what I want is to do it just once, like an alarm,
like threading.Timer

Comment: @Zac You can use the `count` kwarg when decorating the loop. It will specify how many times you want the loop to actually loop for, i.e. `@tasks.loop(count=1, seconds=30)` would only make it run once.

Comment: when i use ```count = 1``` it just send the message once immediately when i use the command and stops.

Comment: is there a way to use ```count = 2 ``` and the first count dont send any messages?

Comment: @Zac You can use `await asyncio.sleep(x)` to sleep for a certain amount of time and then do something? It's the async version of `time.sleep()` if that's of any help at all. There's also [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) if that's more what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Diggy for mentioning `asyncio.sleep`

This is the code that fits what I want and works:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['Timer'])
async def timer(ctx, secs, *message):
    globalsecs = secs
    await ctx.send(f"The timer {message} started and it is going to take {secs} secs to be over.")
    await asyncio.sleep(int(secs))
    await send_message(message = f'Your timer:{message} is over, it took {secs}secs.', ctx = ctx)
    
async def send_message(ctx, message):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple example (for your example with the timer):

```
@client.command(aliases = ['Timer'])
async def timer(ctx, secs, *message):
    if secs < 1:
        await ctx.send("You can't give seconds lower than 1!")
    else:
        timer = await ctx.send(f"Your timer {message} started, and it is gonna take {secs}secs to stop.")
        while True:
            if secs > 0:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                secs -= 1
                await timer.edit(content=f"Your timer {message} started, and it is gonna take {secs}secs to stop.")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f'Your timer: {message} is over, it took {secs} secs.')
```

Maybe this helps you..